# Why doesn't js want to add a class to the safari browser?

Tags: javascript, css

Help me figure out what my mistake is.

I need to add a class to a div that has a class (for example id) only for the safari browser (for example for chrome). Tell me how to make the code work correctly?

```js
var ba =["Chrome","Firefox","Safari","Opera","MSIE","Trident","Edge"];
var b, ua = navigator.userAgent;
for(var i=0; i < ba.length; i++){
    if( ua.indexOf(ba[i]) > -1 ){
        b = ba[i];
        break;
    }
}

if(b == "Chrome") {
document.getElementById("div1").classList.add("class1");
}
```

```css
.class1{
display: inline-block;
 background-color: hsla(0, 69.20%, 55.47%, 1.00);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">

</div>
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: what does it say if you do : `alert(navigator.userAgent);` or `console.log(navigator.userAgent);` ?

Comment: @Aahad I don’t understand why, but this script doesn’t want to work on my website. https://limitedgravity.webflow.io/work .

Comment: @G-Cyrillus alert work good in my site . But when i change to class , this is not working ;(

Comment: Hahaha. The error turned out to be very simple. The code had to be placed in < body>. First I posted in the <head>)).

Comment: @Nicker no! The code had to be called for in `<head>`,either with a `defer` attribute, or wrapped in an event listener for `DOMContentLoaded`. If you want to avoid this kind of "bugs" in the future, take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript